# Eschatology: Reformed and Roman Catholic?

Tags: catholicism, reformed-theology, eschatology, augustine

I've heard that both Reformed and Roman Catholic eschatologies have Augustine as a major foundation. True?

Comment: Well Augustine is an important Christian theology for most Christians. It would be natural to expect this is the case in some way. Protestants have many quite distinct eschatological systems however, so this is really a bit too broad.

Comment: True and thanks - Protestant eschatologies ARE all over the place - that's why I chose a sub-group of Protestantism - Reformed theology. There seems to be a tendency to heavily allegorize half of Daniel and much of Revelation and it seems to be a brother, or at least first cousin, of the way Catholicism has dealt with eschatological issues. I was assuming that tendency came from Augustine. Just wanted to hear from someone who has thought through such a comparison.

Comment: I think Augustine's view is Amillenial so Reformed group that belives in Amillennialism would cohere well with Augustine, as does Roman Catholic.  But I hear that neither Luther and Calvin produced a commentary on Revelation, although their view maybe Amillenial as well.  The question is whether Reformed theology **today** is still united to be Amillenial given that Premillennialism seems to be gaining ground among all stripes of evangelicals?  And YES, you are right that allegorizing principle is what unites Amillenial and Augustine.

Comment: GD - thanks for your input. I do know there are people who hold to some Calvinist tenets who are Millennial - I believe John MacArthur might be an example?

Comment: @rickhess You probably mean Premillennialist?  Yes, John MacArthur is one, see [his sermon series on it](https://www.gty.org/library/topical-series-library/300/why-every-calvinist-should-be-a-premillennialist).  So he probably wouldn't agree with Augustine's eschatological view.  He's a 4-point Calvinist (Reformed), see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._MacArthur).

Comment: Useful guidance - appreciated. I just read the wiki article on MacArthur.  I end up feeling Augustine is at least "a" and quite possibly "the" father of both Roman and Reformed eschatological schools. Thanks for your time.